# Error: Could not find a production build in the '.next' directory when starting Next.js production server

Tags: node.js

I am new to Next.js and I'm encountering an error when trying to start the production server. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
"Error: Could not find a production build in the '/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:345:23)
at new Server (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:151:29)
at new NextNodeServer (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:172:9)
at NextServer.createServer (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:179:24)
at async /home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:200:31
at async NextServer.prepare (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:160:24)
at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/ignacy/strony/next-test/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server.js:123:17) {
type: 'Error'
}"
```

I have followed the Next.js documentation, but this is my first time using it and I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I tried running 'next build' before starting the server, as suggested in the error message, but it didn't solve the problem.

Can someone please help me understand the cause of this error and guide me on how to resolve it? Thank you in advance!